# Finding the suitable CNN architecture for the calssification

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, classification, conv-neural-network

I want to use convolutional Neural Network (CNN) to classify between two classes of images. I built several CNN architectures, but I always get the same result; the network always classify all cases as a second class sample. Therefore, I always get 50% accuracy in leave-one-out. The data is balanced in terms of the number of samples of each class (16 from 1st, and 16 from 2nd). Could you please clarify what does this mean.

Comment: 16 images from each class sounds like too small a training set for training a CNN from scratch. Can you get more samples?

Comment: @paisanco Unfortunately, I can't. I intentionally mentioned the size of the set. However, I read that CNN is more suitable for small training sets.

Answer (score 0):

With such small number of training samples, Your CNN model is very likely to overfit the data giving good training accuracy and worst test accuracy.

Else your model can be skewed predicting the same class at all times.

Below are some of the solutions you can try:

1) As you have commented, if you cannot get any more images, then try creating new images by modifying the ones already available. For ex: Let's say you have 16 images of a cat (cat is the class). You can crop the cat and paste it in different backgrounds, try varying the brightness, intensity etc, Try rotation, translation operations etc.

This will help you create a good training set.

2) Try creating a smaller model (with one or two layers) and check if it improves your accuracy.

3) You can do transfer learning by using a good pre-trained model as it can learn pretty well when compared to creating a model from base.